# Simulate a click on a link with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I need to simulate a click on a link using JavaScript. Could anybody tell me how it can be achieved? It should work in FireFox and IE.

Comment: in jquery it would be `$('#link').trigger('click');`

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned by others, you can use `click` method for IE. For Firefox, have a look at [element.dispatchEvent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.dispatchEvent). See the example in the documentation.

Comment: For those who are too lazy to dig for the example ;-) https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Creating_and_triggering_events#Triggering_built-in_events

Comment: also, this may be useful to help identify when to use this code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9847580/how-to-detect-safari-chrome-ie-firefox-and-opera-browser

Answer (score 4):

```
var el = document.getElementById('link');

// Firefox
if (document.createEvent) {
    var event = document.createEvent("MouseEvents");
    event.initEvent("click", true, true);
    el.dispatchEvent(event);
}
// IE
else if (el.click) {
    el.click();
}
```

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/yP9y8/2/)

Comment: That's strange. I don't have access to IE on a Mac, but it works on Firefox 3.6.13 for me. `click` is a standard method in IE, and I can't see why it shouldn't work in IE. Are you seeing any errors? Did you try the example link I posted below - http://jsfiddle.net/anurag/yP9y8/2/? How about other browsers like Chrome or Safari? Install Firebug for Firefox, or use Developer Tools in Chrome/Safari to see if any errors are showing up.

Comment: There are no errors showing up. It just doesn't initiate the click. The same in the example code you've sent via jsfiddle.net

Comment: Works on FF under Windows

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
document.getElementById('yourLink').click();
```

Comment: I believe ff does not understand click event on links. Could you wrap it up in a span and then simulate the click on it or try below:
window.location.href = document.getElementById('yourLink').href ;

Comment: @Jinesh, sometimes, we need more than a redirect on clicking a link :)

Comment: I wish I could use it. Forbidden in the product I'm working on.

Comment: could you tell me what else do you want to do when you trigger the click? You might be able to put that piece in a function and then directly call it rather than actually trigger the click.

Comment: That link runs a ClickOnce (.NET) application. All I need to do - simulate a click on an existing link.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('mylink').click()
```

Comment: There is no `click` method for a link object as far as I can remember.