# How to detect Safari, Chrome, IE, Firefox and Opera browsers?

Tags: javascript, browser-detection

I have 5 addons/extensions for Firefox, Chrome, Internet Explorer(IE), Opera, and Safari.

How can I correctly recognize the user browser and redirect (once an install button has been clicked) to download the corresponding addon?

Comment: try detectjs, it can be used for all browsers

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Browser detection in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript)

Comment: detect.js is no longer maintained (according to https://github.com/darcyclarke/Detect.js), they recommend https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser

Comment: I used UAParser Plugin, it is written in Vanilla JavaScript. Source: [How to detect browser, engine, OS, CPU, and device using JavaScript?](http://justcode.me/how-to/detect-browser-engine-os-cpu-and-device-using-javascript/)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5916900/how-can-you-detect-the-version-of-a-browser)

Comment: The MDN docs are useful: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent

Comment: I'd like to re-surface this question - is there a reliable & simple answer to this yet?  There are many (old) questions like this on SO and yet most of them work off the `userAgent` function which even w3schools acknowledges is inaccurate.  I've tested some of the answers to this question and similar ones, and none of them seem reliable.  If I'm better off asking a new question please let me know.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2400935/browser-detection-in-javascript

Answer (score 2003, accepted):

Googling for browser reliable detection often results in checking the User agent string. This method is **not** reliable, because it's trivial to spoof this value.
I've written a method to detect browsers by [duck-typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing).

Only use the browser detection method if it's truly necessary, such as showing browser-specific instructions to install an extension. **Use feature detection when possible.**

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/6spj1059/

```js
// Opera 8.0+
var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

// Firefox 1.0+
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

// Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof safari !== 'undefined' && window['safari'].pushNotification));

// Internet Explorer 6-11
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

// Edge 20+
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

// Chrome 1 - 79
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);

// Edge (based on chromium) detection
var isEdgeChromium = isChrome && (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edg") != -1);

// Blink engine detection
var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;


var output = 'Detecting browsers by ducktyping:<hr>';
output += 'isFirefox: ' + isFirefox + '<br>';
output += 'isChrome: ' + isChrome + '<br>';
output += 'isSafari: ' + isSafari + '<br>';
output += 'isOpera: ' + isOpera + '<br>';
output += 'isIE: ' + isIE + '<br>';
output += 'isEdge: ' + isEdge + '<br>';
output += 'isEdgeChromium: ' + isEdgeChromium + '<br>';
output += 'isBlink: ' + isBlink + '<br>';
document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

### Analysis of reliability

The [previous method](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9851769/1) depended on properties of the rendering engine ([`-moz-box-sizing`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/Box-sizing#Browser_compatibility) and `-webkit-transform`) to detect the browser. These prefixes will eventually be dropped, so to make detection even more robust, I switched to browser-specific characteristics:

- Internet Explorer: JScript's [Conditional compilation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ka90k2e(v=vs.94).aspx) (up until IE9) and [`document.documentMode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/cc196988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).
- Edge: In Trident and Edge browsers, Microsoft's implementation exposes the `StyleMedia` constructor. Excluding Trident leaves us with Edge.
- Edge (based on chromium): The user agent include the value "Edg/[version]" at the end (ex: "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.16 Safari/537.36 **Edg/80.0.361.9**").
- Firefox: Firefox's API to install add-ons: [`InstallTrigger`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XPInstall_API_Reference/InstallTrigger_Object)
- Chrome: The global `chrome` object, containing several properties including a documented [`chrome.webstore`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webstore) object.
- Update 3 `chrome.webstore` is deprecated and undefined in recent versions
- Safari: A unique naming pattern in its naming of constructors. This is the least durable method of all listed properties and guess what? In Safari 9.1.3 it was fixed. So we are checking against `SafariRemoteNotification`, which was introduced after version 7.1, to cover all Safaris from 3.0 and upwards.
- Opera: `window.opera` has existed for years, but [will be dropped](https://dev.opera.com/blog/300-million-users-and-move-to-webkit/) when Opera replaces its engine with Blink + V8 (used by Chromium).
- Update 1: [Opera 15 has been released](http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/2013/05/opera-next-15-0-released/), its UA string looks like Chrome, but with the addition of "OPR". In this version the `chrome` object is defined (but `chrome.webstore` isn't). Since Opera tries hard to clone Chrome, I use user agent sniffing for this purpose.
- Update 2: `!!window.opr && opr.addons` can be used to detect [Opera 20+](https://dev.opera.com/extensions/addons.html) (evergreen).
- Blink: `CSS.supports()` [was introduced in Blink](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-supports-api) once Google switched on Chrome 28. It's of course, the same Blink used in Opera.

### Successfully tested in:

- Firefox 0.8 - 61
- Chrome 1.0 - 71
- Opera 8.0 - 34
- Safari 3.0 - 10
- IE 6 - 11
- Edge - 20-42
- Edge Dev - 80.0.361.9

> Updated in November 2016 to include detection of Safari browsers from 9.1.3 and upwards
>
> Updated in August 2018 to update the latest successful tests on chrome, firefox IE and edge.
>
> Updated in January 2019 to fix chrome detection (because of the window.chrome.webstore deprecation) and include the latest successful tests on chrome.
>
> Updated in December 2019 to add Edge based on Chromium detection (based on the @Nimesh comment).

Comment: FYI This doesn't work with Chrome Extensions as ```window.chrome.webstore``` is undefined there. Haven't checked it with Firefox Extensions. 

```is.js``` mentioned elsewhere does work in both Chrome and Firefox Extensions.

Comment: `isSafari` doesn't work with Safari 10. I'm going to argue this is a bad solution (not that I have a good one). There's no guarantee many of the things your checking for won't be removed OR won't be added by other browsers. Every site that was using this code for check for Safari just broke with macOS Sierra or Safari 10 upgrades :(

Comment: @gman I agree with you. This solution works fine when you deploy it, but is not really future-proof as browsers evolves.

Comment: @gman I also agree with you. Regardless, I just evolved my solution to include Safaris from 9.1.3 and up :)

Comment: This breaks JS execution in Safari 10.0.1 as it doesn't know the objects "opr" and window.chrome, therefore I added two checks:

Comment: `var oprAddons = (typeof opr === 'object')? opr.addons : false;`

Comment: `var isOpera = (!!w.opr && !!oprAddons) || !!window.opera || n.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;`

Comment: `var chromeWebstore = (typeof window.chrome === 'object')? window.chrome.webstore : false;`

Comment: `var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!chromeWebstore;`

Comment: I don't know how to insert line breaks in comments so I used several comments. btw., I've no Mac at home so I used macincloud.com for Safari testing. Very slow RDP connection to a virtual Mac but nifty anyway, 24h trial for 99c.

Comment: In Chrome it says "true" also for Blink.

Comment: But has this been tested on the **mobile versions** of those browsers as well as the **desktop versions** too? And truthfully, there are different mobile versions and different desktop versions per platform. So really, firefox has 3 binaries for Windows, Linux, Mac OS, and 2 binaries for Android and iOS.

Comment: I am particularly trying to detect if the browser is Chrome or Firefox, and it seems to work great in Windows, Debian and MacOS for both browsers. In Android, it fails detecting Chrome, and in iPhone it fails for both of them.

Comment: Thank you. Though, just tested on Chrome 55.0.2883.87 m, and it didn't work.

Comment: I'd like to check for chrome and this is definitely not working on latest chrome mobile .55 version :/

Comment: A general question though, why `!!document.documentMode`? Instead this is good without this `!!`.

Comment: Mozilla added the [`runtime.getBrowserInfo()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/getBrowserInfo) WebExtension-API to get information about the browser in which an add-on is running.

Comment: It does not work with desktop version of Safari/603.2.4, anyone knows a solution?

Comment: @LeOpArD add `/constructor/i.test(function HTMLElementConstructor() {}) || ` to the beginning of the safari test

Comment: The current `isSafari` does not work under `<iframe>` under Safari 10.1.2

Comment: ReactJS Addendum: Since React is strongly-typed, this will cause compile-time errors for lack of definition in var's opr and safari.

Comment: Note: When Chrome is run headless, there is no `window.chrome` object.

Comment: I get this error in safari `'safari' is not defined`

Comment: Thanks for the ans. Worked for Desktop but not working in Android phone especially for Chrome. tell me if any solution there,, thanks again...

Comment: "It's trivial to spoof this value" -- Why is this being acknowledged at all? ANY form of browser detection *can* be spoofed. That doesn't matter at all; browser detection is largely a form of convenience to let people know of browser UI hints, known issues, etc., and user agents are a perfectly valid way to do that. This answer feels like a terrible mixed misunderstanding of feature detection vs user agent sniffing, and I'm really not sure why it's so popular. Nothing you've said is technically incorrect, but this is an incredibly unhelpful answer.

Comment: Detecting mobile browser: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11381673/detecting-a-mobile-browser?rq=1

Comment: FYI `!!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;` returns `false` when Chrome is in headless mode.

Comment: Firefox `typeof InstallTrigger` is returning `undefined` for me in Firefox v25. I am using it in the debug console

Comment: Chrome v.64 will report back "Safari".

Comment: window.chrome.webstore is deprecated starting from Chrome ver. 71: https://blog.chromium.org/2018/06/improving-extension-transparency-for.html

Comment: !!window.chrome.webstore return false from chrome on android.

Comment: Chrome test (due to v71 obsolescence) can be fixed by `!!window.chrome && !isOpera`.

Comment: As `chrome` and others are non-standard `window` properties it would be safer to use `window.hasOwnProperty('chrome')`. In other hand I am personally not a big fan of double negation. It is confusing when reading code.

Comment: I think you get less credit so thank you for coming up with a great solution. The usage of navigator.userAgent is rampant and i feel that your direction should be implemented natively.

Comment: Turns out `!!window.chrome && !isOpera` doesn't work as it matches for Edge.

Comment: `!!window.navigator.plugins.namedItem('Chrome PDF Plugin')`

Comment: Its browser version dependent and doen't work in Chrome 71(tested). My code broke and it took lot of time to figure out.

Comment: isChrome: false with Chrome 71 win7

Comment: Can confirm on chrome. Does no work on Chrome 71 & 72.

Comment: var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.Browser && window.Browser.name === 'chrome';
This appropriately identifies Chrome, but excludes Edge. Haven't tested with Opera.

Comment: FYI Edge will be switching to the Chromium engine: https://www.theverge.com/2018/12/4/18125238/microsoft-chrome-browser-windows-10-edge-chromium

Comment: it's false for all on chrome on ios

Comment: Took some time to figure out, so it might help some: `!!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime)` will fail when you open local domains or IPs! Chrome seems to invalidate the runtime when you browse to a local page.

Comment: Adding to @eyecatchUp, it seems that the chrome test works on https pages, but not http pages (without ssl).

Comment: This seems to work better: `var isChrome = !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.csi)`  It at least works when the URL is not SSL and reports correctly on Edge.  I'm not sure about Safari.

Comment: As of right now, my chrome Version 74.0.3729.169 says `isChrome: true` and `isBlink: true` So seems like there is an issue here.

Comment: Why used: `false || !!document.documentMode` if it is equivalent to `!!document.documentMode`? Am I missing something?

Comment: isChrome being true through Opera. Not a problem as Opera behaviour is too similar to Chrome but is still a missmatch.

Comment: "because it's trivial to spoof this value." so what?  If a browser is pretending to be something else, then why should the site care?

Comment: @UKMonkey, have you found any lightweight solution to find a browser using userAgent?

Comment: @Kiura not sure what exactly you mean, but the answer from Nimesh seems to be what you're looking for?

Comment: @UKMonkey, yes, It is what I am looking for. Although I needed more browsers (like Yandex browser, Vivaldi, etc..). So finally I found a library that does what I need, in case other people are interested the library is called bowser

Comment: use document['documentMode'] instead of document.documentMode, if you want to get rid of the error/warning message

Comment: Seems pretty ridiculous to me that we have to go through all this to find out which browser is being used.  I would think it would make sense for the browser vendors to agree on a standard javascript variable they can all send down, some crazy name like 'browserName'!

Comment: Isn’t the Edge Chromium detection of just the substring “Edg” going to match on the old “Edge” (Trident based)?

Comment: Anyone has code to also detect Safari 11, 12 and 13?

Comment: Chrome 80 and 81 are not detected with this. And not Safari on iOS (no idea where it has its version tag).

Comment: This has failed to detect Firefox 78.

Comment: isEdgeChromium is false for Edge Version 83.0.478.61 (Official build) (64-bit). Otherwise this works for the latest Safari, Firefox, and Chrome on Windows 10 and OSX Catalina.

Comment: Safari detection is no longer working as of Safari 14 Beta 2 on macOS 10.15.6 Catalina.

Comment: I'm running Edge Chromium, but it says false for it. Everything is false.

Comment: After reading all the comments I will never use duck typing to detect which browser is being used ever again. Using the userAgent string is not without it's problems but still seems like the best option and is still the preferred method by Google.

Comment: Unfortunately not working under iOS 12.4.9 ipad Air in all three browsers:
Safari, Chrome, Firefox

Comment: Is it intended, that on EdgeChromium and on Opera also isChrome == true?
Besides that, it is kind a cool hack! :)

Comment: Please do not do that. It creates issues down the line for browser implementers and web developpers. When using non standard API for detecting a browser, basically we solidify the existence of this API and makes it part of the Web platform. The more people rely on it, the more the browser implementer will be unable to remove it one day because removing it will break websites.

Comment: @dmikester1—one reason vendors do not want to standardise *navigator.useragent* is because they do not want their users to see "*Your browser is not supported, please download a supported browser from …*" like in the Netscape vs IE days.

Comment: please update it, because it's doesn't work in Edge Chromium,  `(!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime)` always return false

Comment: Chrome 71+ returns false. This answer needs to be updated...

Comment: isChrome: true on edge browser

Comment: Doesn't work in modules it seems, well it's pretty damn stupid that this sort of approach is what one would have to resort to. It's brittle & can change at any time. Well, seeing as its javascript pretty much explains most of it.

Comment: it's not working anymore

Comment: As of 2022, Firefox detection with InstallTrigger is going to break because it's going away around Firefox 103 or so.

Comment: I was trying to use this in a browser  extension background script, but got an error that `'window' is not defined` which is understandable because it's a background script and doesn't have a window. Is there any solution to that?

Comment: This is ever-obsolete.  Instead use https://www.npmjs.com/package/detect-browser

Comment: This solution no longer works in modern browsers, as mentioned above.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get all "false" n MS Edge Version 108.0.1462.46. 
Your answer is extremely overrated with 1900+ upvotes. @Nimesh's answer below has only 184 upvotes and it works!

Comment: For Firefox version 112+ the check for `InstallTrigger` does not work anymore. `typeof mozInnerScreenX !== 'undefined'` might be an alternative.

Answer (score 211):

You can try the following way to check the browser:

```js
function myFunction() {
  if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR')) != -1) {
    alert('Opera');
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edg") != -1) {
    alert('Edge');
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {
    alert('Chrome');
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1) {
    alert('Safari');
  } else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
    alert('Firefox');
  } else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) //IF IE > 10
  {
    alert('IE');
  } else {
    alert('unknown');
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>
  <p>What is the name(s) of your browser?</p>
  <button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>
  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

And if you need to know only IE Browser version then you can follow below code. This code works well for version IE6 to IE11

```js
function getInternetExplorerVersion() {
  var ua = window.navigator.userAgent;
  var msie = ua.indexOf("MSIE ");
  var rv = -1;

  if (msie > 0 || !!navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident.*rv\:11\./)) // If Internet Explorer, return version number
  {

    if (isNaN(parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))))) {
      //For IE 11 >
      if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
        var ua = navigator.userAgent;
        var re = new RegExp("Trident/.*rv:([0-9]{1,}[\.0-9]{0,})");
        if (re.exec(ua) != null) {
          rv = parseFloat(RegExp.$1);
          alert(rv);
        }
      } else {
        alert('otherbrowser');
      }
    } else {
      //For < IE11
      alert(parseInt(ua.substring(msie + 5, ua.indexOf(".", msie))));
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Click on Try button to check IE Browser version.</p>

  <button onclick="getInternetExplorerVersion()">Try it</button>

  <p id="demo"></p>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why would one write so many lines of code? userAgent is ambiguous.

Comment: What about Microsoft Edge?

Comment: doesn't work. Using Chrome 51 and user agent includes Safari string: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.103 Safari/537.36

Comment: the answer above checks for chrome  before checking for safari. because safari will not have `chrome` keyword in the useragent. example of safari useragent - `mozilla/5.0 (macintosh; intel mac os x 10_11_5) applewebkit/601.6.17 (khtml, like gecko) version/9.1.1 safari/601.6.17`

Comment: Stackoverflow uses this method

Comment: Work smoothly on Chrome 55, Firefox 50 and IE 11, but not on Edge 38.14393.0.0 (shows "Chrome"). Thank you.

Comment: Edge has safari in it, need to check edge prior to safari

Comment: and what we should write for chrome in ipad?

Comment: When testing this in Opera (latest version), this returns 'Chrome' for me. To fix this, I changed the Opera if statement to: `if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR') != -1 )`

Comment: At least use a switch block.

Comment: For some reason my `navigator.userAgent` in chrome includes Safari: `"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36"` but my firefox does not: `"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0"`

Comment: I've heard `navigator.userAgent` is unreliable because of spoofing...

Comment: Which is expected and desired: if someone sets their UA to a different browser, they're doing that to get the content that would get served for that browser. User agent spoofing is literally why you want a browser detection solution based on userAgent instead of using duck typing, as you're generating different content for different browsers (as opposed to trying to implement progressive enhancement based on JS support, which should use duck typing because you'd need feature detection).

Comment: This is my userAgent string in Chrome!!

```'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/98.0.4758.102 Safari/537.36'```

This method doesn't work since it contains Safari and Mozilla too.

Comment: Yes! This works! You should get the most upvotes, not the first answer, which got 1900 upvotes and it doesn't work.

Comment: it doesn't handle brave browser

Comment: @GorvGoyl Brave will never work because they intentionally hide it from the user agent. Check https://github.com/brave/browser-laptop/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#090

Comment: @alexandernst there's a way https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36523448/how-do-i-tell-if-a-user-is-using-brave-as-their-browser

Comment: This detects Chrome on IOS as Safari! Take care

Comment: I was able to detect Chrome on iOS by using `if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf('Chrome') != -1) || (navigator.userAgent.indexOf('CriOS') != -1))` ...apparently on iOS Chrome uses **CriOS** in the user agent (at least on the devices I have tested)

Answer (score 83):

Here are several prominent libraries that handle browser detection as of Dec 2019.

#### [Bowser](https://github.com/lancedikson/bowser) by lancedikson - 4,065★s - Last updated Oct 2, 2019 - 4.8KB

```js
var result = bowser.getParser(window.navigator.userAgent);
console.log(result);
document.write("You are using " + result.parsedResult.browser.name +
               " v" + result.parsedResult.browser.version + 
               " on " + result.parsedResult.os.name);
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/bowser@2.7.0/es5.js"></script>
```

**supports Edge based on Chromium*

---

#### [Platform.js](https://github.com/bestiejs/platform.js/) by bestiejs - 2,550★s - Last updated Apr 14, 2019 - 5.9KB

```js
console.log(platform);
document.write("You are using " + platform.name +
               " v" + platform.version + 
               " on " + platform.os);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/platform/1.3.5/platform.min.js"></script>
```

#### [jQuery Browser](https://github.com/gabceb/jquery-browser-plugin) by gabceb - 504★s - Last updated Nov 23, 2015 - 1.3KB

```js
console.log($.browser)
document.write("You are using " + $.browser.name +
               " v" + $.browser.versionNumber + 
               " on " + $.browser.platform);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-browser/0.1.0/jquery.browser.min.js"></script>
```

#### [Detect.js (Archived)](https://github.com/darcyclarke/Detect.js) by darcyclarke - 522★s - Last updated Oct 26, 2015 - 2.9KB

```js
var result = detect.parse(navigator.userAgent);
console.log(result);
document.write("You are using " + result.browser.family +
               " v" + result.browser.version + 
               " on " + result.os.family);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Detect.js/2.2.2/detect.min.js"></script>
```

#### [Browser Detect (Archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20131114025336/http://www.quirksmode.org:80/js/detect.html) by QuirksMode - Last updated Nov 14, 2013 - 884B

```js
console.log(BrowserDetect)
document.write("You are using " + BrowserDetect.browser +
               " v" + BrowserDetect.version + 
               " on " + BrowserDetect.OS);
```

```html
<script src="https://kylemit.github.io/libraries/libraries/BrowserDetect.js"></script>
```

---

### Notable Mentions:

- [WhichBrowser](https://github.com/WhichBrowser/Parser-PHP) - 1,355★s - Last updated Oct 2, 2018
- [Modernizr](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr) - 23,397★s - Last updated Jan 12, 2019 - To feed a fed horse, feature detection should drive any [canIuse](https://caniuse.com/) style questions.  Browser detection is really just for providing customized images, download files, or instructions for individual browsers.

### Further Reading

- [**Stack Overflow** - Browser detection in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2400935/1366033)
- [**Stack Overflow** - How can you detect the version of a browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49582577/1366033)

Comment: Well worth a few Kb of overhead to not reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 72):

I know it may be overkill to use a lib for that, but just to enrich the thread, you could check [is.js](http://arasatasaygin.github.io/is.js/) way of doing this:

```
is.firefox();
is.ie(6);
is.not.safari();
```

Comment: Just worth noting  that under the hood it's primarily doing User-Agent detection. Supplemented with vendor detection / some feature detection  in places.

Comment: @TygerKrash sure, you are absolutely right. That is actually what I meant with my answer: open the source code of `is.js` and check how they do it.

Comment: jQuery used to include similar properties: $.browser.msie... Were removed from version 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/jquery.browser/

Comment: @RafaelEyng: I think the issue with it doing User-Agent detection is that this method is unreliable.

Comment: This is definitely the most robust approach when you assume that the UA string hasn't been modified. It also properly detects OS (android, win, mac, linux); device type (desktop, tablet, mobile). It can also test for version of browser.

Comment: is.js Bug: is.Chrome() returns false on the Google Chrome of all iOS Devices. MacOS on Chrome works.

Answer (score 50):

In case anyone finds this useful, I've made [Rob W's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9851769/540552) into a function that returns the browser string rather than having multiple variables floating about. Since the browser also can't really change without loading all over again, I've made it cache the result to prevent it from needing to work it out the next time the function is called.

```js
/**
 * Gets the browser name or returns an empty string if unknown. 
 * This function also caches the result to provide for any 
 * future calls this function has.
 *
 * @returns {string}
 */
var browser = function() {
    // Return cached result if avalible, else get result then cache it.
    if (browser.prototype._cachedResult)
        return browser.prototype._cachedResult;

    // Opera 8.0+
    var isOpera = (!!window.opr && !!opr.addons) || !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;

    // Firefox 1.0+
    var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';

    // Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
    var isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);

    // Internet Explorer 6-11
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

    // Edge 20+
    var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;

    // Chrome 1+
    var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;

    // Blink engine detection
    var isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;

    return browser.prototype._cachedResult =
        isOpera ? 'Opera' :
        isFirefox ? 'Firefox' :
        isSafari ? 'Safari' :
        isChrome ? 'Chrome' :
        isIE ? 'IE' :
        isEdge ? 'Edge' :
        isBlink ? 'Blink' :
        "Don't know";
};

console.log(browser());
```

Comment: in Edge browser, it returns *Chrome*

Comment: @eFriend I updated the answer to the latest browser tests.

Comment: I like this, but I would have preferred a fallback to userAgent(), instead of "Don't know".

Comment: Property `window.chrome.webstore` was removed in Chrome 71, so this approach is no longer working.

Comment: you can overwrite the function with a function that simply returns the cachedResult and omit the if statement. The first time around you have to still return the result.
browser = function(){ return  cachedResult};
return cachedResult;

Comment: Says _Don't know_ for Microsoft's new Chrome version of Edge.

Comment: I tried this in Safari, Firfox, and Chrome, always returns `Don't know`.

Answer (score 49):

Short variant (**update 10 july 2020 mobile browser detection fix**)

```js
var browser = (function() {
    var test = function(regexp) {return regexp.test(window.navigator.userAgent)}
    switch (true) {
        case test(/edg/i): return "Microsoft Edge";
        case test(/trident/i): return "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
        case test(/firefox|fxios/i): return "Mozilla Firefox";
        case test(/opr\//i): return "Opera";
        case test(/ucbrowser/i): return "UC Browser";
        case test(/samsungbrowser/i): return "Samsung Browser";
        case test(/chrome|chromium|crios/i): return "Google Chrome";
        case test(/safari/i): return "Apple Safari";
        default: return "Other";
    }
})();
console.log(browser)
```

**Typescript version:**

```
export enum BROWSER_ENUM {
  EDGE ,
  INTERNET_EXPLORER ,
  FIRE_FOX ,
  OPERA ,
  UC_BROWSER ,
  SAMSUNG_BROWSER ,
  CHROME ,
  SAFARI ,
  UNKNOWN ,
}

const testUserAgent = (regexp: RegExp): boolean => regexp.test(window.navigator.userAgent);

function detectBrowser(): BROWSER_ENUM {
  switch (true) {
    case testUserAgent(/edg/i): return BROWSER_ENUM.EDGE;
    case testUserAgent(/trident/i): return BROWSER_ENUM.INTERNET_EXPLORER;
    case testUserAgent(/firefox|fxios/i): return BROWSER_ENUM.FIRE_FOX;
    case testUserAgent(/opr\//i): return BROWSER_ENUM.OPERA;
    case testUserAgent(/ucbrowser/i): return BROWSER_ENUM.UC_BROWSER;
    case testUserAgent(/samsungbrowser/i): return BROWSER_ENUM.SAMSUNG_BROWSER;
    case testUserAgent(/chrome|chromium|crios/i): return BROWSER_ENUM.CHROME;
    case testUserAgent(/safari/i): return BROWSER_ENUM.SAFARI;
    default: return BROWSER_ENUM.UNKNOWN;
  }
}

export const BROWSER: BROWSER_ENUM = detectBrowser();

export const IS_FIREFOX = BROWSER === BROWSER_ENUM.FIRE_FOX;
```

**Functional algorithm, just for fun:**

```
 var BROWSER =  new Array(
     ["Microsoft Edge", /edg/i],
     ["Microsoft Internet Explorer", /trident/i],
     ["Mozilla Firefox", /firefox|fxios/i],
     ["Opera", /opr\//i],
     ["UC Browser", /ucbrowser/i],
     ["Samsung Browser", /samsungbrowser/i],
     ["Google Chrome", /chrome|chromium|crios/i],
     ["Apple Safari", /safari/i],
     ["Unknown", /.+/i],
 ).find(([, value]) => value.test(window.navigator.userAgent)).shift();
```

Comment: If you dislikes me, please explain why.

Comment: this will show 'safari' while browsing with 'chrome' on ios

Comment: This method worked with Chrome and Firefox on desktop and Safari on iOS. It fails with Chrome and Firefox on iOS.

Comment: @BReddy retest this please, I haven't any apple device:)

Comment: I tested this with Firefox (78.0.1 on Win10), Chrome (83.0 on Win10), Edge (83.0 on Win10 - Chromium base), Firefox(27 on iOS), and Chrome (83.0 on iOS) successfully. This logic still reported Safari (on iOS 13.5.1) still reported as 'chrome'. Could this be because Chromium is derived from WebKit base?

Comment: @BReddy yes all webkits are similar, but have some different features.But browsers can have different useragents on ios. For example firefox and chrome on ios have fxios and crios strings. Retest it please)

Comment: It does work on both Chrome and Safari on macOs.
@BReddy: Order does matter here, hence the Safari check needs to be after Chrome.

Comment: this works for me since I'm targeting Chrome, Edge, Firefox (later Safari) only. But is it currently reliable for all browsers?

Comment: @Gangula it currently reliable for all browsers that you see in a code)Microsoft Edge,Microsoft Internet Explorer,Opera,Firefox,Uc,samsung,chrome,safari

Answer (score 15):

No idea if it is useful to anyone but here is a variant that would make TypeScript happy:

```
export function getBrowser() {

 // Opera 8.0+
    if ((!!window["opr"] && !!["opr"]["addons"]) || !!window["opera"] || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0) {
        return 'opera';
    }

    // Firefox 1.0+
    if (typeof window["InstallTrigger"] !== 'undefined') {
        return 'firefox';
    }

    // Safari 3.0+ "[object HTMLElementConstructor]" 
    if (/constructor/i.test(window["HTMLElement"]) || (function(p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || (typeof window["safari"] !== 'undefined' && window["safari"].pushNotification))) {
        return 'safari';
    }

    // Internet Explorer 6-11
    if (/*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document["documentMode"]) {
        return 'ie';
    }

    // Edge 20+
    if (!(/*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document["documentMode"]) && !!window["StyleMedia"]) {
        return 'edge';
    }

    // Chrome 1+
    if (!!window["chrome"] && !!window["chrome"].webstore) {
        return 'chrome';
    }

    // Blink engine detection
    if (((!!window["chrome"] && !!window["chrome"].webstore) || ((!!window["opr"] && !!["opr"]["addons"]) || !!window["opera"] || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0)) && !!window["CSS"]) {
        return 'blink';
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you have some ifs with "false" as a condition?

Comment: @YonatanNir I think it's meant to detect conditional compilation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Microsoft_Extensions/at-cc-on

Comment: Typescript say the same with this: Argument of type '{ new (): HTMLElement; prototype: HTMLElement; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'

Answer (score 13):

Thank you, everybody. I tested the code snippets here on the recent browsers: Chrome 55, Firefox 50, IE 11 and Edge 38, and I came up with the following combination that worked for me for all of them. I'm sure it can be improved, but it's a quick solution for whoever needs:

```
var browser_name = '';
isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 && !isEdge)
{
    browser_name = 'chrome';
}
else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1 && !isEdge)
{
    browser_name = 'safari';
}
else if(navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) 
{
    browser_name = 'firefox';
}
else if((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true )) //IF IE > 10
{
    browser_name = 'ie';
}
else if(isEdge)
{
    browser_name = 'edge';
}
else 
{
   browser_name = 'other-browser';
}
$('html').addClass(browser_name);
```

It adds a CSS class to the HTML, with the name of the browser.

Comment: did you test chrome on ios?

Answer (score 12):

You can use `try` and `catch` to use the different browser error messages.
IE and edge were mixed up, but I used the duck typing from Rob W (based on this project here: https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/i-have-opera/2395080328).

```
var getBrowser = function() {        
    try {
        var e;
        var f = e.width;
    } catch(e) {
        var err = e.toString();

        if(err.indexOf("not an object") !== -1) {
            return "safari";
        } else if(err.indexOf("Cannot read") !== -1) {
            return "chrome";
        } else if(err.indexOf("e is undefined") !== -1) {
            return "firefox";
        } else if(err.indexOf("Unable to get property 'width' of undefined or null reference") !== -1) {
            if(!(false || !!document.documentMode) && !!window.StyleMedia) {
                return "edge";
            } else {
                return "IE";
            }
        } else if(err.indexOf("cannot convert e into object") !== -1) {
            return "opera";
        } else {
            return undefined;
        }
    }
};
```

Comment: That's a great idea: you don't need neither "window", nor "navigator" objects!

Comment: My suggestion is to get rid document and window completely. See IE chunk:

            return "firefox";
        } else if(err.search("[object Error]") !== -1 && e.message != null && e.description != null){
   return "IE";
        } else if(err.search("cannot convert e into object") !== -1){
            return "opera";

Comment: How does that differentiate between IE and edge?

Comment: Strange, I can't reproduce err.search("[object Error]") anymore. Anyway, for me firefox vs chrome vs some thing else is enough. I use it in a PAC file where window and document objects are not available.

Comment: Just figured out the cause. It looks like that for funning a PAC file Windows 7 does not use IE11, which is installed at my machine, but rather IE7-like  engine (probably from the Windows host). So err.toString() there gives "[object Error]" while inside the IE11 it gives "Unable to get property..." string as in your code. So, the code above should fail with the IE7.

Comment: Running Chrome 67 and Opera 54 (OS X), they both return the same error string :(

Answer (score 11):

Here's a 2016 adjusted version of Rob's answer, including Microsoft Edge and detection of Blink:

(*edit*: I updated Rob's answer above with this information.)

```js
// Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
// Firefox 1.0+
isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';
// Safari 3.0+
isSafari = /constructor/i.test(window.HTMLElement) || (function (p) { return p.toString() === "[object SafariRemoteNotification]"; })(!window['safari'] || safari.pushNotification);
// Internet Explorer 6-11
isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
// Edge 20+
isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
// Chrome 1+
isChrome = !!window.chrome && !!window.chrome.webstore;
// Blink engine detection
isBlink = (isChrome || isOpera) && !!window.CSS;

/* Results: */
console.log("isOpera", isOpera);
console.log("isFirefox", isFirefox);
console.log("isSafari", isSafari);
console.log("isIE", isIE);
console.log("isEdge", isEdge);
console.log("isChrome", isChrome);
console.log("isBlink", isBlink);
```

The beauty of this approach is that it relies on browser engine properties, so it covers even derivative browsers, such as Yandex or Vivaldi, which are practically compatible with the major browsers whose engines they use. The exception is Opera, which relies on user agent sniffing, but today (i.e. ver. 15 and up) even Opera is itself only a shell for Blink.

Comment: The `!!window.MSAssertion;` test doesn't work for me in the Edge beta via Remote Desktop. It returns false.

Comment: @NoR What version of Edge are you using? It matters

Comment: The VM Version: 20150801 --- Edge Version: 20.10240.16384.0

Comment: @NoR Oh you're using the VM... The `MSAssertion` trick is adjusted to version 25. But since many devs rely on the VMs, I'll try to adjust it this older version. Good call. Thanks.

Comment: @NoR Updated - should be futureproof. The `StyleMedia` (capitalized) object is specific to IE and Edge and doesn't seem to be going anywhere.

Comment: @IssacGable let's fix it - which version?

Comment: @pilau Safai Version 10.1.2 (12603.3.8)

Comment: I have also found [UAParser](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js) a js plugin that still maintained and has be highly accurate and easy to use.

Comment: Property `window.chrome.webstore` was removed in Chrome 71, so this approach is no longer working.

Answer (score 8):

If you need to know what is the numeric version of some particular browser you can use the following snippet. Currently it will tell you the version of Chrome/Chromium/Firefox:

```
var match = $window.navigator.userAgent.match(/(?:Chrom(?:e|ium)|Firefox)\/([0-9]+)\./);
var ver = match ? parseInt(match[1], 10) : 0;
```

Answer (score 7):

There is also a less "hacky" method which works for all popular browsers.
Google has included a browser-check in their [Closure Library](https://developers.google.com/closure/). In particular, have a look at [`goog.userAgent`](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.userAgent.html) and [`goog.userAgent.product`](https://google.github.io/closure-library/api/goog.userAgent.product.html). In this way, you are also up to date if something changes in the way the browsers present themselves (given that you always run the latest version of the closure compiler.)

Comment: Most of the answers here are not concerned with being "hacky" if they are the only reliable method.  userAgent, as noted multiple times, is easily spoofed, and is therefore, unreliable.

Answer (score 7):

[UAParser](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js) is one of the JavaScript Library to identify browser, engine, OS, CPU, and device type/model from userAgent string.

There's an CDN available. Here, I have included a example code to detect browser using UAParser.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ua-parser-js@0/dist/ua-parser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var parser = new UAParser();
    var result = parser.getResult();
    console.log(result.browser);     // {name: "Chromium", version: "15.0.874.106"}
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Now you can use the value of `result.browser` to conditionally program your page.

Source Tutorial: [How to detect browser, engine, OS, CPU, and device using JavaScript?](https://justcode.me/how-to/detect-browser-engine-os-cpu-and-device-using-javascript/)

Comment: a [thousand](https://github.com/faisalman/ua-parser-js/blob/master/src/ua-parser.js) lines of code you call lightweight?

Answer (score 6):

Detecting Browsers on Desktop and Mobile : Edge, Opera, Chrome, Safari, Firefox, IE

> I did some changes in @nimesh code now it is working for Edge also,
>   and Opera issue fixed:

```
function getBrowserName() {

    if ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Edge") > -1 && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Edge') > -1 ) {
        return 'Edge';
    }
    else if( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Opera") != -1 || navigator.userAgent.indexOf('OPR') != -1 )
    {
        return 'Opera';
    }
    else if( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1 )
    {
        return 'Chrome';
    }
    else if( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Safari") != -1)
    {
        return 'Safari';
    }
    else if( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1 ) 
    {
        return 'Firefox';
    }
    else if( ( navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1 ) || (!!document.documentMode == true ) ) //IF IE > 10
    {
        return 'IE';
    }  
    else 
    {
        return 'unknown';
    }
}
```

**Thanks @nimesh user:2063564**

Comment: It's picking up Safari when I'm in Chrome...

Answer (score 6):

**Detecting Browser and Its version**

This code snippet is based on the article from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Browser_detection_using_the_user_agent). Where they gave a brief hint about various keywords that can be used to detect the browser name.

[image: reference]

The data shown in the image above is not sufficient for detecting all the browsers e.g. *userAgent of Firefox will have Fxios as a keyword rather than Firefox.*

A few changes are also done to detect browsers like **Edge** and **UCBrowser**

The code is currently tested for the following browsers by changing userAgent with the help of dev-tools ([How to change userAgent](https://www.howtogeek.com/113439/how-to-change-your-browsers-user-agent-without-installing-any-extensions/)):

- FireFox
- Chrome
- IE
- Edge
- Opera
- Safari
- UCBrowser

```js
getBrowser = () => {
    const userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    let browser = "unkown";
    // Detect browser name
    browser = (/ucbrowser/i).test(userAgent) ? 'UCBrowser' : browser;
    browser = (/edg/i).test(userAgent) ? 'Edge' : browser;
    browser = (/googlebot/i).test(userAgent) ? 'GoogleBot' : browser;
    browser = (/chromium/i).test(userAgent) ? 'Chromium' : browser;
    browser = (/firefox|fxios/i).test(userAgent) && !(/seamonkey/i).test(userAgent) ? 'Firefox' : browser;
    browser = (/; msie|trident/i).test(userAgent) && !(/ucbrowser/i).test(userAgent) ? 'IE' : browser;
    browser = (/chrome|crios/i).test(userAgent) && !(/opr|opera|chromium|edg|ucbrowser|googlebot/i).test(userAgent) ? 'Chrome' : browser;;
    browser = (/safari/i).test(userAgent) && !(/chromium|edg|ucbrowser|chrome|crios|opr|opera|fxios|firefox/i).test(userAgent) ? 'Safari' : browser;
    browser = (/opr|opera/i).test(userAgent) ? 'Opera' : browser;

    // detect browser version
    switch (browser) {
        case 'UCBrowser': return `${browser}/${browserVersion(userAgent,/(ucbrowser)\/([\d\.]+)/i)}`;
        case 'Edge': return `${browser}/${browserVersion(userAgent,/(edge|edga|edgios|edg)\/([\d\.]+)/i)}`;
        case 'GoogleBot': return `${browser}/${browserVersion(userAgent,/(googlebot)\/([\d\.]+)/i)}`;
        case 'Chromium': return `${browser}/${browserVersion(userAgent,/(chromium)\/([\d\.]+)/i)}`;
        case 'Firefox': return `${browser}/${browserVersion(userAgent,/(firefox|fxios)\/([\d\.]+)/i)}`;
        case 'Chrome': return `${browser}/${browserVersion(userAgent,/(chrome|crios)\/([\d\.]+)/i)}`;
        case 'Safari': return `${browser}/${browserVersion(userAgent,/(safari)\/([\d\.]+)/i)}`;
        case 'Opera': return `${browser}/${browserVersion(userAgent,/(opera|opr)\/([\d\.]+)/i)}`;
        case 'IE': const version = browserVersion(userAgent,/(trident)\/([\d\.]+)/i);
            // IE version is mapped using trident version 
            // IE/8.0 = Trident/4.0, IE/9.0 = Trident/5.0
            return version ? `${browser}/${parseFloat(version) + 4.0}` : `${browser}/7.0`;
        default: return `unknown/0.0.0.0`;
    }
}

browserVersion = (userAgent,regex) => {
    return userAgent.match(regex) ? userAgent.match(regex)[2] : null;
}

console.log(getBrowser());
```

Comment: Only this one worked for me. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You can use Detect-browser.js, JavaScript library that detects and prints an object of browser information including browser language/name, user agent, device type, user OS, referer, online/0ffline, user timezone, screen resolution, and cookie enabled.

Get it from here [detect-browser.js](https://www.cssscript.com/detect-browser-information-javascript/)

it will give you something like that:

[image]

Comment: This is definitely the best solution, as all other approaches are not actively maintained in the ever-changing world of browsers.

Answer (score 5):

Here is my customized solution.

```js
        const inBrowser = typeof window !== 'undefined'
        const UA = inBrowser && window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase()
        const isIE =
          UA && /; msie|trident/i.test(UA) && !/ucbrowser/i.test(UA).test(UA)
        const isEdge = UA && /edg/i.test(UA)
        const isAndroid = UA && UA.indexOf('android') > 0
        const isIOS = UA && /iphone|ipad|ipod|ios/i.test(UA)
        const isChrome =
          UA &&
          /chrome|crios/i.test(UA) &&
          !/opr|opera|chromium|edg|ucbrowser|googlebot/i.test(UA)
        const isGoogleBot = UA && /googlebot/i.test(UA)
        const isChromium = UA && /chromium/i.test(UA)
        const isUcBrowser = UA && /ucbrowser/i.test(UA)
        const isSafari =
          UA &&
          /safari/i.test(UA) &&
          !/chromium|edg|ucbrowser|chrome|crios|opr|opera|fxios|firefox/i.test(UA)
        const isFirefox = UA && /firefox|fxios/i.test(UA) && !/seamonkey/i.test(UA)
        const isOpera = UA && /opr|opera/i.test(UA)
        const isMobile =
          /\b(BlackBerry|webOS|iPhone|IEMobile)\b/i.test(UA) ||
          /\b(Android|Windows Phone|iPad|iPod)\b/i.test(UA)
        const isSamsung = UA && /samsungbrowser/i.test(UA)
        const isIPad = UA && /ipad/.test(UA)
        const isIPhone = UA && /iphone/.test(UA)
        const isIPod = UA && /ipod/.test(UA)
    
        console.log({
          UA,
          isAndroid,
          isChrome,
          isChromium,
          isEdge,
          isFirefox,
          isGoogleBot,
          isIE,
          isMobile,
          isIOS,
          isIPad,
          isIPhone,
          isIPod,
          isOpera,
          isSafari,
          isSamsung,
          isUcBrowser,
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

```
var BrowserDetect = {
        init: function () {
            this.browser = this.searchString(this.dataBrowser) || "Other";
            this.version = this.searchVersion(navigator.userAgent) || this.searchVersion(navigator.appVersion) || "Unknown";
        },
        searchString: function (data) {
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var dataString = data[i].string;
                this.versionSearchString = data[i].subString;

                if (dataString.indexOf(data[i].subString) !== -1) {
                    return data[i].identity;
                }
            }
        },
        searchVersion: function (dataString) {
            var index = dataString.indexOf(this.versionSearchString);
            if (index === -1) {
                return;
            }

            var rv = dataString.indexOf("rv:");
            if (this.versionSearchString === "Trident" && rv !== -1) {
                return parseFloat(dataString.substring(rv + 3));
            } else {
                return parseFloat(dataString.substring(index + this.versionSearchString.length + 1));
            }
        },

        dataBrowser: [
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Edge", identity: "MS Edge"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "MSIE", identity: "Explorer"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Trident", identity: "Explorer"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Firefox", identity: "Firefox"},
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Opera", identity: "Opera"},  
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "OPR", identity: "Opera"},  

            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Chrome", identity: "Chrome"}, 
            {string: navigator.userAgent, subString: "Safari", identity: "Safari"}       
        ]
    };

    BrowserDetect.init();


    var bv= BrowserDetect.browser;
    if( bv == "Chrome"){
        $("body").addClass("chrome");
    }
    else if(bv == "MS Edge"){
     $("body").addClass("edge");
    }
    else if(bv == "Explorer"){
     $("body").addClass("ie");
    }
    else if(bv == "Firefox"){
     $("body").addClass("Firefox");
    }


$(".relative").click(function(){
$(".oc").toggle('slide', { direction: 'left', mode: 'show' }, 500);
$(".oc1").css({
   'width' : '100%',
   'margin-left' : '0px',
   });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Chrome & Edge introduced a new [User-Agent Client Hints API](https://web.dev/migrate-to-ua-ch/) for this:

```
navigator.userAgentData.brands.map(item => item.brand).includes('Google Chrome')
```

Firefox & Safari don't support it yet unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

To check for IE browser using following code.

```
console.log(/MSIE|Trident/.test(window.navigator.userAgent))
```

OR

```
var isIE = !!document.documentMode; 

console.log(isIE)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This method is currently valid for detecting all browsers. I quoted the vue-element-admin template

```
 export function fnBrowserDetect() {
      var browserName = (function(agent) {
        switch (true) {
          case agent.indexOf('edge') > -1: return 'MS Edge'
          case agent.indexOf('edg/') > -1: return 'Edge (chromium based)'
          case agent.indexOf('opr') > -1 && !!window.opr: return 'Opera'
          case agent.indexOf('chrome') > -1 && !!window.chrome: return 'Chrome'
          case agent.indexOf('trident') > -1: return 'MS IE'
          case agent.indexOf('firefox') > -1: return 'Mozilla Firefox'
          case agent.indexOf('safari') > -1: return 'Safari'
          default: return 'other'
        }
      })(window.navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase())
      return browserName.toLowerCase()
    }
```

Comment: I have so many questions for this code... Why switch(true)?!

Comment: @SimonC I'm thinking the reason behind `switch(true)` is to avoid writing a while loop of any kind

My question though is what is `window.opr` or `window.chrome`?? They aren't properties of the window class from all that I've read.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window

Comment: @CarloNyte window.chrome seems to be a Chrome extension and not something defined in the standard. I would be slightly worried if Google did a Microsoft and defined itself as the standard - and got away with it

Answer (score 1):

```js
import getAgent, { getAccurateAgent } from "@egjs/agent";

const agent = getAgent();
getAccurateAgent().then((accurate_agent)=>{
    console.log(agent,'accurate.');
})
console.log(agent);
```

https://github.com/naver/egjs-agent

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the real answer is that 90% of the time, you can't reliably detect any specific browser.

The most reliable way for your use case is to provide a download button for each browser and let the user - who knows *for certain* what browser they are on "tell you." *All* of the detection methods shown in these other answers will either eventually stop working, or can easily be faked.

User-agent strings can be overridden by the user.

Browsers, over time, trend toward removing unique API differences. (Source: look at Internet Explorer over the years)

If you *must* use browser detection, use a well-updated library to do so. So long as you keep that library up-to-date, you can be assured that the detection will not fail - so long as it's not too reliant upon UA strings.

---

For other use cases, don't use browser detection - use feature detection. Modern Firefox supports everything - if not more - that Chrome does, and generally is closer to the w3 & etc. specs. A tool called "browserlist" is a great tool to determine which browsers' features your code should use. Tools like Webpack, Parcel, Babel, and more use this - so you can use the latest browser features without having to write the compatibility code yourself.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://jsfiddle.net/wvbdnb8o/422/) combines both Rob's original answer and Pilau's update for 2016

```
    var isOpera = !!window.opera || navigator.userAgent.indexOf(' OPR/') >= 0;
    // Opera 8.0+ (UA detection to detect Blink/v8-powered Opera)
var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';   // Firefox 1.0+
var isSafari = Object.prototype.toString.call(window.HTMLElement).indexOf('Constructor') > 0;
    // At least Safari 3+: "[object HTMLElementConstructor]"
var isChrome = !!window.chrome && !isOpera;              // Chrome 1+
var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;
// Edge 20+
var isEdge = !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia;
// Chrome 1+
var output = 'Detecting browsers by ducktyping:<hr>';
output += 'isFirefox: ' + isFirefox + '<br>';
output += 'isChrome: ' + isChrome + '<br>';
output += 'isSafari: ' + isSafari + '<br>';
output += 'isOpera: ' + isOpera + '<br>';
output += 'isIE: ' + isIE + '<br>';
output += 'isIE Edge: ' + isEdge + '<br>';
document.body.innerHTML = output;
```

Comment: Is there a point to telling the user what browser they're using?  I imagine they'd already know this.

Comment: @HoldOffHunger it's main intention was more to adapt the most compatible code to the active browser, rather than to inform the user which browser they're using. Unless the browser they're using is super outdated and has been excluded from backwars compatibility, in which it wouldn't hurt to let the user know they can benefit from a better experience should they switch to something more up to date

Comment: If that's really what this code is for, don't use this approach. Use feature detection instead. Does the browser support promises? if so, use it. If not, complain to the user or apply a polyfill.

Answer (score -1):

Here you find out which browser is it running.

```
function isValidBrowser(navigator){

            var isChrome =  navigator.indexOf('chrome'),
            isFireFox= navigator.indexOf('firefox'),
            isIE = navigator.indexOf('trident') ,
            isValidChromeVer = parseInt(navigator.substring(isChrome+7, isChrome+8)) >= 4,
            isValidFireForVer = parseInt(navigator.substring(isFireFox+8, isFireFox+9)) >= 3,
            isValidIEVer = parseInt(navigator.substring(isIE+8, isIE+9)) >= 7;

            if((isChrome > -1 && isValidChromeVer){ console.log("Chrome Browser")}

            if(isFireFox > -1 && isValidFireForVer){ console.log("FireFox  Browser")}

            if(isIE > -1 && isValidIEVer)){ console.log("IE Browser")}


        }
```

Answer (score -1):

We can use below util methods

```
utils.isIE = function () {
        var ver = navigator.userAgent;
        return ver.indexOf("MSIE") !== -1 || ver.indexOf("Trident") !== -1; // need to check for Trident for IE11
    };

    utils.isIE32 = function () {
        return (utils.isIE() && navigator.appVersion.indexOf('Win64') === -1);
    };

    utils.isChrome = function () {
        return (window.chrome);
    };

    utils.isFF64 = function () {
        var agent = navigator.userAgent;
        return (agent.indexOf('Win64') >= 0 && agent.indexOf('Firefox') >= 0);
    };

    utils.isFirefox = function () {
        return (navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().indexOf('firefox') > -1);
    };
```

Comment: The `agent.indexOf('Win64')` check fails on Firefox 122 on Linux. This is because Linux is not Windows. This check will fail on MacOS, iOS, and Android as well.

Answer (score -1):

```
const isChrome = /Chrome/.test(navigator.userAgent)
const isFirefox = /Firefox/.test(navigator.userAgent)
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not a good answer. Edge has Chrome in his userAgent message. It's better to use  !!window.chrome && (!!window.chrome.webstore || !!window.chrome.runtime);

Comment: your answer also fail for Opera browser

Answer (score -1):

Simple:

```js
var OSName="Unknown OS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) OSName="Windows";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) OSName="MacOS";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("X11")!=-1) OSName="UNIX";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux")!=-1) OSName="Linux";
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Linux x86_64")!=-1) OSName="Ubuntu";

var nVer = navigator.appVersion;
var nAgt = navigator.userAgent;
var browserName  = navigator.appName;
var fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
var majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
var nameOffset,verOffset,ix;

// In Opera, the true version is after "Opera" or after "Version"
if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Opera"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Opera";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+6);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In MSIE, the true version is after "MSIE" in userAgent
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("MSIE"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Microsoft Internet Explorer";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+5);
}
// In Chrome, the true version is after "Chrome" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Chrome"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Chrome";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
}
// In Safari, the true version is after "Safari" or after "Version" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Safari"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Safari";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+7);
 if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Version"))!=-1) 
   fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In Firefox, the true version is after "Firefox" 
else if ((verOffset=nAgt.indexOf("Firefox"))!=-1) {
 browserName = "Firefox";
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+8);
}
// In most other browsers, "name/version" is at the end of userAgent 
else if ( (nameOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf(' ')+1) < 
          (verOffset=nAgt.lastIndexOf('/')) ) 
{
 browserName = nAgt.substring(nameOffset,verOffset);
 fullVersion = nAgt.substring(verOffset+1);
 if (browserName.toLowerCase()==browserName.toUpperCase()) {
  browserName = navigator.appName;
 }
}
// trim the fullVersion string at semicolon/space if present
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(";"))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);
if ((ix=fullVersion.indexOf(" "))!=-1)
   fullVersion=fullVersion.substring(0,ix);

majorVersion = parseInt(''+fullVersion,10);
if (isNaN(majorVersion)) {
 fullVersion  = ''+parseFloat(navigator.appVersion); 
 majorVersion = parseInt(navigator.appVersion,10);
}

document.write(''
 +'Hey! i see you\'re using '+browserName+'! <br>'
 +'The full version of it is '+fullVersion+'. <br>'
 +'Your major version is '+majorVersion+', <br>'
 +'And your "navigator.appName" is '+navigator.appName+'. <br>'
 +'Your "navigator.userAgent" is '+navigator.userAgent+'. <br>'
)

document.write('And, your OS is '+OSName+'. <br>');
```

Comment: I came from android with microsoft edge browser. Your code says that I am "ubuntu with chrome"

Answer (score -1):

You can detect it like:

```
if (typeof navigator !== 'undefined' && navigator.userAgent && navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase().match(/firefox\/(\d+)/)) {
   alert('Firefox');
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
var BrowserType;
(function (BrowserType) {
    BrowserType["OPERA"] = "Opera";
    BrowserType["OPERA2"] = "OPR";
    BrowserType["EDGE"] = "Edg";
    BrowserType["CHROME"] = "Chrome";
    BrowserType["SAFARI"] = "Safari";
    BrowserType["FIREFOX"] = "Firefox";
    BrowserType["UNKNOWN"] = "unknown";
})(BrowserType || (BrowserType = {}));
const detectBrowser = () => {
    return Object.values(BrowserType).find((browser) => navigator.userAgent.indexOf(browser) != -1);
};
console.log(detectBrowser());
```

Answer (score -1):

```
const getBrowserName = () => {
    var userAgent = navigator.userAgent;
    var browser_names = ['Firefox', 'Chrome', 'Safari', 'Edge', 'Opera', 'MSIE', 'OPR', 'Trident/']
    var browser_name = "Unknown Browser"

    for (let i = 0; i < browser_names.length; i++) {
      if (userAgent.indexOf(browser_names[i]) > -1) {
          browser_name = browser_names[i]
          return browser_name
      }
    }
    return browser_name
  }
```

Less verbose than others

Answer (score -3):

Simple, single line of JavaScript code will give you the name of browser:

```
function GetBrowser()
{
    return  navigator ? navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase() : "other";
}
```

Comment: The userAgent alone doesn't tell us enough.  For example, my user agent is "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.85 Safari/537.36", which mentions Mozilla, Chrome and Safari.  Which browser type am I?

Comment: Sorry but I didn't get you for "Which browser type am I?" what you want to get?

Comment: @NiravMehta What he meant is that `navigator.userAgent` tells you every browser possible you have.. So this is really not reliable, the only case it would work is if the user only has one browser.

Comment: this is not a reliable way to detect browser. Some useragents includes both chrome and safari, so there is not way to detect which one should we consider and last but, not the least, useragent can be modified  by the web page.